# If the file in __autoload has a Syntax Error, then the script stops without show a message

Tags: php, syntax, autoload, require-once

I have an __autoload function defined for load classes automatically, if that file has a syntax error, the script stops, simply stops... without error...

```
function __autoload( $var_class )
{
    require_once( "$var_class.php" );
}
echo "Before load...";
new ClassName();
echo "Hello world...";
```

Output:

**Before load...**

***How to show de SYNTAX ERROR?***

Comment: ClassName.php has a syntax error...

Comment: Looks like you answered your own question. For the future you can make sure errors are enabled to see what it is: `error_reporting(E_ALL) ; ini_set('display_errors', 1)`.

Comment: question is ... "How to show de SYNTAX ERROR?" ... normally flow, I have error_reporting enabled, ini_set too......

Comment: Then Fanis has answered your question.

Comment: OK for this example works, but in my code don't... I don't know...

Answer (score 0):

Shows the error for me:

```
class ClassName
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $line = $error
        echo 'Contructor' . "\n";
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Before load...
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_ECHO in ClassName.php on line 8
```

See Fanis' comment.

Comment: Doesn't works, I don't know what's happening, I did an example like this question, and shows the error, but not in my code...

Comment: I don't know what's wrong with this, but I solved putting Fani's instructions inside the autoload function... Why doesn't works in the global scope?